# How to reference and populate nested schemas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**TL;DR**
How do you reference (and thus populate) subdocuments within the same collection?

I've been trying for a while now to populate a reference to a subdocument in my Mongoose schema. I have a main schema (MainSchema) which holds arrays of locations and contacts. The locations have a reference to these contacts.

In my location array i make a reference to these contacts by the _id of the contact. See below.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const LocationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  city: {type: String},
  contact: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Contact' //alternative tried: refPath: 'contacts'
  } 
});
const Location = mongoose.model('Location', LocationSchema);

const ContactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {type: String},
  lastName: {type: String}
});
const Contact = mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema );

const MainSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String},
  locations: [LocationSchema],
  contacts: [ContactSchema]    
});

export.default mongoose.model('Main', 'MainSchema');
```

Now when i want to populate the contact of the locations I get null or just the plain _id string returned. Below is my populate code. I've tried every combination i could find, involving making the nested documents their own models and trying different ways to reference them.

```
MainSchema.statics = {
  get(slug) {
    return this.findOne({name})
      .populate('locations.contact')
      .exec()
      .then((company) => {
        if (company) {
          return company;
        }
        const err = 'generic error message';
        return Promise.reject(err);
      });
    }
  };
```

I've also tried the newer approach to no avail:

```
populate({
  path: 'locations',
  populate: {
    path: 'contacts',
    model: 'Contact'
  }
});
```

I must be missing something here. But what?

*edited the question to show the complete query statement as requested*

Comment: Can you put the whole query? not just the `populate` in the last snippet? so I can better understand what you are trying to achive

Comment: `.populate({path : 'locations', populate : {path: 'contacts'}})` should work, Also in your example from the first snippet I don't see the `export` functions for the other two models, do you have that defined?

Comment: Does your arrays `locations: [LocationSchema]` and `contacts: [ContactSchema]` contain the reference `_id` ? from the other schemas

Comment: @Sabbin Thanks for the comments. I've added the model statements. My locations array contains a reference to the contact._id. When i try your suggestion the query returns this reference as is, so no populate yet.

Comment: in your `MainSchema` you have `locations: [LocationSchema]`, does that have the reference ID from the `LocationSchema` ? in the database, you should have an array with the with `MongoDB` objectId's there

Comment: The `locations` array has items with `._id`, `.city` and `.contact`. `contact` contains the `ObjectId(...)` that matches an item in the `contacts` array.

Comment: did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @Sabbin I did not, unfortunately.

Comment: I have a similar example in my app, but I'm using a different to link the documents, I use only the `_id` from one to another not the entire schema as you use, if you want I'll post an answer with my approach

Comment: @Sabbin Please do, i hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching some more i found an exact same case posted as an issue on the Mongoose github [issue tracker](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3244).

According to the prime maintainer of Mongoose this form of populate is not possible:

> If you're embedding subdocs, you're not going to be able to run
>   populate() on the array, because the subdocs are stored in the doc
>   itself rather than in a separate collection.

Answer (score 0):

So taking your example of schema I would do the following. Please take notice that I don't say that my approach is the best way of doing this, but I had an exact similar case as you.

> Mongoose model

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const LocationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    city: {type: String},
    contact: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Contact'}
});

const ContactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {type: String},
    lastName: {type: String}
});


const MainSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    locations: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Location' }],
});

const Main = mongoose.model('Main', MainSchema);
const Location = mongoose.model('Location', LocationSchema);
const Contact = mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema );
```

Note: In your main schema I've removed the contacts since I understand from your example that each location has it's own contact person, so actually in the `MainSchema` you don't need the `ContactSchema`

> The controller where the you insert the data

The idea here is that you have to pass the reference `_id` from each document to the other one, the below example is mock-up please adapt it to fit your `app`. I used a `data` object that I assume that has one location and one person contact

```
async function addData(data) {

    //First you create your Main document
    let main = await new Main({
        name: data.name
    }).save();

    //Create the contact document in order to have it's _id to pass into the location document
    let contact = await new Contact({
        firstName: data.fistName,
        lastName: data.lastName
    });

    //Create the location document with the reference _id from the contact document
    let location = await new Location({
        city: data.city,
        contact: contact._id
    }).save();

    //Push the location document in you Main document location array
    main.locations.push(location);
    main.save();

    //return what ever you need
    return main;
}
```

> Query

```
let mainObj = await Main.findOne({name})
    .populate({path: 'locations', populate: {path: 'contact'}})
    .exec();
```

This approach is working for me, hope it serves you as well

Comment: Thanks for the extended example. The issue here is that it requires the contacts to live in their own collection. My goal is to have both contacts and locations exist in the main collection. This reduces the amount of code on my front-end and should keep things more contained and easy to manage. If only i could reference one array item from another array item in the same collection.

Comment: So for me better understand... the contacts are and are not dependable by location? I mean you also need to have all of the contact people in the `Main` collection without the location?

Comment: In my example you have `Main` -> `Location` -> `Contacts`, you need to have the contacts as well in the `Main` and in the `Location` ?

Comment: I want to reference the contacts in my main collection from the locations in my main collection, so i won't have to duplicate any data while keeping it all in the main collection. I'll have more items that will reference each other and this seemed like the most code-efficient and overhead-free solution

Comment: The example above does exactly that, as far as I understood the above comment. You have referenced the contacts in your `Main` collection from the `Location` collection

Comment: For your `Main` you can have multiple `Locations` each with one `Contact`